# In react, localStorage and window.localStorage both null when fetching auth-token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

In the `App.js` of our react application, created several years ago using create-react-app, we check to see if a user is already logged in via a `useEffect()` that checks `localStorage` for a prior authentication token. Sometimes, we run into errors. Directly posting sentry error seems like a lazy way to post on this issue, however it also seems like the clearest and most effective way to articulate the issue:

[image]

Because we are using the ternary operator, presumably the error is being thrown for `window.localStorage.getItem('auth-token')`, i.e `window.localStorage` seems to be null. My plan to fix is to simply also check that `window.localStorage` is not null:

```
let token = localStorage ? localStorage.getItem('auth-token') : (window.localStorage ? window.localStorage.getItem('auth-token') : null)
```

I think this solution will work okay, even if not the perfect solution. My main question is why is it that `localStorage` and `window.localStorage` are sometimes null - shouldn't these always have some value even if an empty string? Also, is there a more proper way to get `auth-token`s from localStorage that I'm missing here? The double ternary operators, and using window.localStorage as the fallback for lcoalStorage, don't quite seem 100% proper.

Comment: My guess is that there is no entry in the localstorage for the key "auth-token" so that would return null as expected.

Comment: the error seems to imply that the code is running `null.getItem()` which means either `localStorage` or `window.localStorage` is null. Given the ternary operator, the only culprit is `window.localStorage`. I don't believe the error has to do with there being no entry in localStorage for the auth-token

Comment: I wonder if local storage is not implemented or disabled somehow on that particular browser. Some kind of private mode? Or perhaps even full.

Comment: what if the user made `window.localStorage` null  on purpose?

Comment: Is there a way to set `localStorage` to null? I wasn't able to, but I could set `localStorage.getItem` to null, which I don't think would produce that error